# Drawing predefined number of dots inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying achieve the following:
-Given two variables numberColumns/numberRows I want to draw a grid of rectangles or dots in a set width canvas for example 800x400

I have tried several things, but I fail at getting the rectangles/dots the right size with the right spacing

This is an example I tried to draw one row. I am trying to get to work on any given number of rows/columns

```
    function draw(){
            var width = 800;
            var height = 400;

            var nrow = 32;
            var ncol = 48;

            var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');
            if (canvas.getContext){
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                //Have a border so drawing starts at 20,20
                var spacew = width - 40;
                var x = Math.floor(spacew/ncol);

                var currCol = 20;
                for(i = 1; i<ncol; i++){
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(currCol, 20, x, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();

                    currCol = currCol + x*2;
                }

            }
        }
```

Any idea on how I would go about this, maybe an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an example here http://jsfiddle.net/J9MLq/7/. Each circle has a diameter that is a `2*radius`. i have put it when calculating the radius dynamically depending on the width of canvas in `var x = width/ncol/2;` (You don't need any Math.floor/Math.ceil, otherwise you will have gaps between circles and also borders). Also, now canvas element is resizable, your function accepts parameters `draw(width, height)`. Now you can play with the rows by yourself. You can extend the function to accept rows and columns amount as well. Just try it there...

Comment: Thanks it worked. Sometimes the dot arcs get cut off though / there are spaces between the dots. Is there anyway around this?
http://jsfiddle.net/J9MLq/8/

Comment: The problem resides within the coordinates currCol and currRow, because the result of calculation is a fraction and during draw process, thus after some fixed iteration you can observe overlapping of circles etc. This [http://jsfiddle.net/J9MLq/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/J9MLq/12/) is an example where circles are drawn proportionally to the given width/height and space between rows/columns increase respectively.
Second [example - http://jsfiddle.net/J9MLq/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/J9MLq/11/) has no gaps between the circles, but their radius is proportional to width and height together.

Comment: I hope above examples would give you options to play with the coordinates using Math functions.